# Pin application to screen and user can't close or resize or switch between app!

Tags: autostart

I want to create auto login user just when ubuntu starts the specific app automate start as fullscreen and user can't close that app or open other app and switch between app or minimize or ... , only that specific app run.
Is there any solution for me?

Comment: I'd say best approach is to have `openbox` desktop which is minimalistic, i.e. usual UI elements won't get in the way, and via a script that can combine the app with `wmctrl`. The later app allows setting windows as top-most and fullscreen via command-line, ao it can be automated.

Comment: Thanks, I used `wmctrl -r firefox -b toggle,fullscreen` but steel user can close the app or open another app.

Comment: And for keeping the app on top , use `-b toggle, above`. As far as  closing the program, well, there's not that much that we can do here, unless the program is made to ignore shortcuts like Alt+F4. Potentially you could set that as custom shortcut in desktop configuration, but I doubt that's going to be effective.